# jqGrid: Combining sortableRows and gridDnD (Duplicate Rows)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I want to be able to drag items from Grid1 to Grid2 and then allow the user to sort the items of Grid2. Individually, the sortableRows option and gridDnd options work without issue. When both integrations are used together and the user sorts the rows within Grid2, the rows are duplicated as if they were dragged from Grid1.

Using jquery 1.4.4, jqueryui 1.8.10, jqGrid 4.2
Here is some sample code demonstrating the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Creating grid1
    jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 100,
        colNames: ['Id1', 'Name1', 'Values1'],
        colModel: [
           {name: 'id1', index: 'id',width: 100}, 
           {name: 'name1',index: 'name',width: 100},
           {name: 'values1',index: 'values',width: 200}
        ],
        caption: 'Grid 1',
        pager: '#pgrid1'
    });

    // Creating grid2
    jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 'auto',
        colNames: ['Id2', 'Name2', 'Values2'],
        colModel: [
           {name: 'id2',index: 'id',width: 100},
           {name: 'name2',index: 'name', width: 100},
           {name: 'values2',index: 'values',width: 200}],
        caption: 'Grid 2',
        pager: '#pgrid2'
    });

    // Data for grid1
    var mydata1 = [
        {id1:"1",name1:"test1",values1:'One'},
        {id1:"2",name1:"test2",values1:'Two'},
        {id1:"3",name1:"test3",values1:'Three'}
    ];

    // Data for grid2
    var mydata2 = [
        {id2:"11",name2:"test11",values2:'One1'},
        {id2:"21",name2:"test21",values2:'Two1'},
        {id2:"31",name2:"test31",values2:'Three1'}
    ];

    // Adding grid data
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata1.length; i++) {
        jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('addRowData',i + 1, mydata1[i]);
        jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid('addRowData',i + 1, mydata2[i]);
    }

    // connect grid1 with grid2
    jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#grid2'});
    // make grid2 sortable
    jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid('sortableRows');

});

</script>
<table id="grid1">
    <tr>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="grid2">
    <tr>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug in the jqGrid code. I think that one should change the line [392](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.jqueryui.js#L392) of the `grid.jqueryui.js` from

```
return d;
```

to

```
return false;
```

The corresponding line in the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` has the number 11098. After the changes [the original demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/gridDnD-and-sortableRows0.htm) will be fixed to [the following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/gridDnD-and-sortableRows.htm) which seems work correct.

**UPDATED**: I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/duplicate-rows-if-sortablerows-and-griddnd-are-used-together/#p25174) in the trirand forum where I described the problem and my suggestion to fix it. I hope that Tony will include the fix in the main code of jqGrid.

**UPDATED 2**: The bug is already [fixed](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/51604734696533cffe6f6b1b52e91ec8d10acba7) in the main code of jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

Oleg: I get your example page and modified it to make the first grid sortable as well like this :
I added this line at the end of source code : jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('sortableRows'); and the first grid cannot be sorted like the second one, so we could not combining sortableRows and Dnd on the same grid ? What do you think ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /*global jQuery */
    /*jslint browser: true */
    jQuery(function () {
        'use strict';
        var mydata1 = [ // Data for grid1
                {id1: "1", name1: "test1", values1: 'One'},
                {id1: "2", name1: "test2", values1: 'Two'},
                {id1: "3", name1: "test3", values1: 'Three'}
            ],
            mydata2 = [ // Data for grid2
                {id2: "11", name2: "test11", values2: 'One1'},
                {id2: "21", name2: "test21", values2: 'Two1'},
                {id2: "31", name2: "test31", values2: 'Three1'}
            ];

        // Creating grid1
        jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata1,
            height: 'auto',
            colNames: ['Id1', 'Name1', 'Values1'],
            colModel: [
                {name: 'id1', index: 'id', width: 100},
                {name: 'name1', index: 'name', width: 100},
                {name: 'values1', index: 'values', width: 200}
            ],
            caption: 'Grid 1',
            pager: '#pgrid1'
        });

        // Creating grid2
        jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata2,
            height: 'auto',
            colNames: ['Id2', 'Name2', 'Values2'],
            colModel: [
                {name: 'id2', index: 'id', width: 100},
                {name: 'name2', index: 'name', width: 100},
                {name: 'values2', index: 'values', width: 200}
            ],
            caption: 'Grid 2',
            pager: '#pgrid2'
        });

        // connect grid1 with grid2
        jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('gridDnD', {connectWith: '#grid2'});

        // make grid2 sortable
        jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid('sortableRows');
  **jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('sortableRows');**
    });
//]]>
</script>
```