# Use gridDnD and sortableRows in the Same jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

After a long day try to find solution, I finally ask for help,

This is my situation:
I have 3 jqGrid: A, B and C.
A => (can be drag and drop) B,C (add new row to B or C)

B <=> C  and C <=> B (B,C are the same and can be transfer data together)

Everything still OK with gridDnD, until i got new request from customer, that they want rows in grid B and C can also sortable

I have tried to use sortableRows function, but it seem to be  sortableRows doesn't working with gridDnD.
Have you ever face this case?

Can someone help me to solve this? Or any advice to help me?

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? Look at [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/gridDnD-and-sortableRows.htm) created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8156539/315935).

Comment: Hi, I use the latest version of jqGrid, i tried this demo, but the second jqGrid can only drop, can not drag to first jqGrid. And if i set the second grid can drag, the sortableRows will fail